# Webscraping the stock names from a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, stock

I've been trying to webscrape stock names from:
https://www.avanza.se/aktier/hitta.html?sectorId=17&s=numberOfOwners.desc&o=1000&sectorName=Bioteknik%20%26%20L%C3%A4kemedel&cc=SE
To create a list of "AstraZeneca", "Oncopeptides", "AegirBio", etc.

When inspecting the elements, it seems as their names should be within `"span"`, or possibly `"span _ngcontent-sos-c195"`, but I just cannot seem to get it right.

I have successfully webscraped information from this website:
https://news.cision.com/se/braincool?k=BrainCool

Through inspecting the element and finding "h2" as the element of the titles.
But when trying to do it as the same method this time, it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

I begin with:

```
link <- "https://www.avanza.se/aktier/hitta.html?sectorId=17&s=numberOfOwners.desc&o=1000&sectorName=Bioteknik%20%26%20L%C3%A4kemedel&cc=SE"

page <- read_html(link)
```

And then I've tried a bunch of things:

```
title_names <- page %>% html_nodes("[_ngcontent-wiw-c195='']") %>%
  html_attr("span")
ERROR CODE: Error in substring(literal, lenseq, lenseq) : invalid substring arguments

title_names <- page %>% html_nodes("span[_ngcontent-wiw-c195='']") %>% html_text()
ERROR CODE: Error in substring(literal, lenseq, lenseq) : invalid substring arguments

title_names <- page %>% html_nodes("span")
```

(Just doesn't work, no error code but the list is empty)

```
title_names <- page %>% html_nodes("span _ngcontent-bpt-c195")
```

(Just doesn't work, no error code but the list is empty)

I just don't know how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

df <- "https://www.avanza.se/_api/market-stock-filter/stocks" %>%
  request() %>%
  req_body_json(list(
    filter = list(sectorId = 17,
                  countryCode = "SE"),
    limit = 2024,
    offset = 0,
    sortBy = list(field = "numberOfOwners",
                  order = "desc")
  )) %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>%
  pluck("stocks") %>% 
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 1,243 x 17
   orderbookId type  name      shortName currency countryCode directYield priceEarningsRatio quote$last lastPrice oneDayChangePercent oneWeekChangePercent startOfYearChangePer~1
   <chr>       <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    <chr>             <dbl>              <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>               <dbl>                <dbl>                  <dbl>
 1 5431        STOCK AstraZen~ AZN       SEK      SE               0.0195              47.1    1548      1548                  0.0049              -0.0187                 0.103 
 2 52300       STOCK Novo Nor~ NOVO B    DKK      DK               0.0113              40.7    1099.     1099.                 0.0306               0.0101                 0.172 
 3 730897      STOCK Oncopept~ ONCO      SEK      SE               0                   -2.64      8.68      8.68              -0.0023              -0.131                 -0.286 
 4 1108920     STOCK AegirBio  AEGIR     SEK      SE               0                   -0.45      1.44      1.44              -0.0028              -0.0137                -0.284 
 5 742357      STOCK Intervacc IVACC     SEK      SE               0                   -5.75      5.38      5.38              -0.0236              -0.0958                -0.793 
 6 863757      STOCK Callidit~ CALTX     SEK      SE               0                  -13.2      86.7      86.7                0.0123              -0.0888                -0.0622
 7 549022      STOCK Cantargia CANTA     SEK      SE               0                   -2.06      4.08      4.08              -0.0159              -0.0681                 0.325 
 8 791946      STOCK BioArcti~ BIOA B    SEK      SE               0                   76.1     282       282                  0.0159              -0.125                  0.0368
 9 237353      STOCK Vivesto   VIVE      SEK      SE               0                   -0.98      0.294     0.294              0.028               -0.0034                -0.323 
10 674279      STOCK SynAct P~ SYNACT    SEK      SE               0                  -18.4      74.4      74.4                0.0406               0.0391                -0.0871
# i 1,233 more rows
# i abbreviated name: 1: startOfYearChangePercent
# i 8 more variables: quote$oneDayChangePercent <dbl>, $oneWeekChangePercent <dbl>, $startOfYearChangePercent <dbl>, $oneYearChangePercent <dbl>, oneYearChangePercent <dbl>,
#   numberOfOwners <int>, hasPosition <lgl>, hasAnalysis <lgl>
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```